# Tumblr Photoset Captions not working with Magnific Popup

Tags: javascript, tumblr, magnific-popup

I am using a `Tumblr` theme that has `Magnific Popup` pre-installed.

The problem is that the individual `caption` of a `photo` in a `Photoset` does not appear anywhere.
I am guessing that the script does not know where to take that information from (`Tumblr` hasn't been very helpful with their ambiguous `{JSPhototsetLayout}` either).

Do you have any idea how to solve this?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Just found out that the captions of individual photos in a Tumblr Photoset are actually considered alt (alt='The caption of the photo').

I am guessing that all I have to do is to replace "title" with "alt" somewhere in Magnific Popup's code. Do you happen to know where?

Answer (score 0):

You don't (and shouldn't) have to replace anything in Magnific Popup's code, as far as I see in [their docs](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#options) you just have to search your theme to see where Magnific Popup is initialized and tell it where to get the caption from:

```
image: {
    titleSrc: 'alt'
}
```

I have no idea how Tumblr themes are structured but this approach seems pretty straight forward. Try a search in project (or something similar) in your IDE for the "magnificPopup" keyword, it should eventually lead to the bit of code similar to the one in the link above.